# How to draw a marker which is not triangle in SVG?

Tags: svg

For example, like this rectangle marker

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `<marker>` element in a `<def>`. You can then add markers at the start and end by referring to its id with `marker-start="url(#id)"` (or use marker-mid or marker-end). You can define whatever shape you like within the marker tag. The example below is just a vertical line as in your example.

```
<defs>
    <marker id="marker-bar"
            refX="0" refY="5"
            markerHeight="20"
            markerWidth="20"
            viewBox="0 0 10 10"
            orient="auto"
            markerUnits="strokeWidth">
        <path stroke="#111" d="M0 0 v10"/>
    </marker>
</defs>

<path stroke="#111" fill="none"
      d="M152,172 C62,174 190,28 192,122"
      marker-end="url(#marker-bar)"/>
```